# Retrofit2 does not fetch data in android app after publishing on play store

Tags: android, google-play, retrofit2, release

I have created an android app which uses retrofit2 for fetching data from server. It works absolutely fine in debug mode but after publishing it on App store, it does not fetch data.

While creating release apk in android studio it was giving errors, so I put following code in proguard-rules.pro file:

```
     # for retrofit2
     -dontwarn retrofit2.**
     -keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
     -keepattributes Signature
     -keepattributes Exceptions

     -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
     @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
     }

     ## Square Picasso specific rules ##
     ## https://square.github.io/picasso/ ##

     -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
     -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

     # OkHttp
     -keepattributes Signature
     -keepattributes *Annotation*
     -keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
     -keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
     -dontwarn okhttp3.**

     ## Google Play Services 4.3.23 specific rules ##
     ## https://developer.android.com/google/play-                                             
     #Proguard ##

     -keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
     protected Object[][] getContents();
     }

     -keep public class                   
     com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
       public static final *** NULL;
     }

     -keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
     -keepclassmembernames class * {
     @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
     }

     -keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
         public static final ** CREATOR;
     }

     # Okio
     -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
     -dontwarn java.nio.file.*
     -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
     -dontwarn okio.**



     ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android          apps ---------
     -optimizationpasses 5
     -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
     -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
     -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
     -dontpreverify
     -verbose
     -dump class_files.txt
     -printseeds seeds.txt
     -printusage unused.txt
     -printmapping mapping.txt
     -optimizations          !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

     -allowaccessmodification
     -keepattributes *Annotation*
     -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
     -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
     -repackageclasses ''

     -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
     -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
     -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
     -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
     -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
     -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
     -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
     -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
     -dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

     # Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
     # is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
     -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID;
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[]                   
     serialPersistentFields;
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
     java.lang.Object readResolve();
     }

     # Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
     -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
      native <methods>;
      }

     -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
         public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
     }

     -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
         public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, 
      int);
     }

     # Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be 
     accessed
     # through introspection.
     -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
       public static <fields>;
     }

     # Preserve the special static methods that are required in all 
     enumeration classes.
     -keepclassmembers enum * {
         public static **[] values();
         public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
     }

     -keep public class * {
         public protected *;
     }

     -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
       public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
     }
     -keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
     -keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
     -keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
     -keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

     -dontwarn android.support.**
     -dontwarn com.google.ads.**
     -keepattributes Signature
     -keepattributes *Annotation*
     -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
     -keep class com.example.model.** { *; }
```

I know nothing about proguard rules used in android, I just put whatever I found on internet just to avoid all errors.

Comment: First, include the error message or stack trace. Second, are you sure you are using `@SerializedName` annotation in all the fields of your model classes? Third, if you're not sure how to use proguard, disable it by setting `minifyEnabled false` from the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I updated sdk and resolved other errors and set minifyEnabled false. It worked. Thanks.